# Android USB Debugging on 7.1.1 Nougat - does not work

Tags: android, adb, android-7.0-nougat

I have Nexus 5X with android 7.1.1, beta program, with Build number: NPF26F and nothing happens when I connect it to the laptop, OSX. I get nothing in adb devices, and the notification with Usb Debugging does not appear on the phone.

I've tried to connect Nexus 5, with android 6.0.0, and everything worked fine.

I've tried to remove sdk folder, and clean-install everything related to 7.1.1, just in case. Still same result.

My friend also has Nexus 5X on beta program and OSX, and everything worked fine on his phone/laptop; but his phone does not work on mine. Also I've tried my phone on his laptop and it worked. But it did not work on another laptop in linux.

I am confused on what could cause the issue.

Shall I roll out of beta program and try again? or is it about the OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out, the problem was with my cable usb to type-c . It just randomly has broken.

Comment: Since there is no real answer here to the question, can we remove this question?

Comment: Maybe, but still it might make sense for some people to triple-check all their cables before looking for a hardware/software solution.